# How to extract lines between same patterns from a file

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression

How can extract the lines between two patterns which are not unique ?

Example:-

```
data of type samplex
name a
property b
data of type samplex
name c
property d
data of type samplex
name e
property f
data of type sampley
name g
property h
```

I want to search between the pattern "data of type samplex" and get all occurrences of the lines between them.

```
First occurrence:- 
name a
property b

Second occurrence:-
name c
property d

Third occurrence:- 
name e
property f
```

For getting the first occurrence alone and when the two patterns are different,

```
sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p;/pattern2/q' <file> will work.
```

How can I tweak this command for my requirement?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: I'm confused if the `sampley` in the last one is a typo, or if you want everything from `data of type samplex` to `data of type anything`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the *exact* output you want to see. Do you want to have the string `Nth occurrence:-` added? Do you want to remove the lines after `sampley`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's:data of type samplex:\n:g' File_name -i
```

This code will replace the said string with newline so that you will get required info. Use `-i` option to save the changes in original file only.

Comment: This also prints the lines after `sampley`. I don't think the OP wants that.

Comment: I assume it's typo

Comment: I think not - sample x and sample y, based on what they said they want, but it is not very clear...

Comment: OP has this line `between two patterns which are not unique` in question, so I suppose `sampley` was deliberately added

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

```
grep "data of type samplex" -A 2 <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my possibly wrong interpretation of what you want... Obviously you could shorten it if you can match less than the whole phrase.

```
sed -n '/data\ of\ type\ samplex/,/data\ of\ type\ sampley/{s/data\ of\ type\ sample[xy]//; p}' file
```

`-n` quiet, don't print anything until we want output
`[xy]` match either x or y here
`s/data\ of\ type\ sample[xy]//` delete the matched pattern leaving an empty line
`p` print whatever is left after all that

Output:

```
name a
property b

name c
property d

name e
property f
```

I haven't figured out how to add an incremented "Nth occurrence :-" in the case that you want it though

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:**

- The input file has various sections demarcated by `data of type` followed by keyword like `samplex`, `sampley`, etc
- Extracting required: all text falling under particular section

Input file has been modified slightly to reflect corner cases

```
$ cat ip.txt 
data of type samplex
name a
property b
data of type samplez
name 1
property 2
data of type samplex
name e
property f
data of type sampley
name g
property h
data of type samplex
name c
property d
```

In solution below, `$match` is set to `1` if section matches, else `0` when input line is `data of type`. Then input lines are printed until next section starts. This way a section at end of file is also taken care.

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/data of type /){$match=/samplex$/} elsif($match){print}' ip.txt
name a
property b
name e
property f
name c
property d

$ perl -ne 'if(/data of type /){$match=/samplez$/} elsif($match){print}' ip.txt
name 1
property 2

$ perl -ne 'if(/data of type /){$match=/sampley$/} elsif($match){print}' ip.txt
name g
property h
```